# Bootstrap Validator submits form even if there is a validation error

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have the following image where you can plainly see that the field is required after I submit the form.
[image]

However, after submitting the form, it continues on to the button click event in the JS **instead of stopping the form submission.**

**What am I missing here with BootStrap Validator where I can prevent the form from being submitted if there are validation errors?**

### Here is my HTML5 MasterPage pertinent parts

```
<script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/validator.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

Here is my JS which gets initialized, but when run, I get the error stated in my comments:

```
 $('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'enabled',

        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            txtSPStatusComments: {
                selector: '#txtSPStatusComments',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The title is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

### Here is my HTML5

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class='form-group'>
    <span class="label label-default col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">Enter the reason and comments to stop the Shipping Request</span>
    <br />
    <label class="required col-sm-1 control-label" for="txtSPStatusComments">Status Comments:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
      <textarea id="txtSPStatusComments" rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control height-auto" placeholder="Enter Comments" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    <div class="hide-text">
      <input type="hidden" id="txtSPStopGridID" />
    </div>
    <div id="SPmessages"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" id="btnSPAcceptShippingReq" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

### EDIT - WITH BootstrapValidator in place

### MasterPage

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/js-css-menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/js-css-menu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- page specific plugin styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/datepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootbox3/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrapValidator/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

    <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


    <script src="../Scripts/Common.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/CreditSourceDocs.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/StopPenalize.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/PISIQueue.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/BalanceReview.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body class="no-skin">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

### HTML

```
<div class='form-group'>                                                    
   <label class="required col-sm-1 control-label" for="txtSPStatusComments">Status Comments:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
              <textarea id="txtSPStatusComments" name="txtSPStatusComments" rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control height-auto" placeholder="Enter Comments"></textarea>
         </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="submit" id="btnSPAcceptShippingReq" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                    </div>
```

### JS

Note that the code inside this function gets executed on the onDocumentReady event. I see it get executed when the page finishes loading.

```
$('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
        submitButtons: 'button[type="submit"]',
        fields: {
            txtSPStatusComments: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Status Comments required!'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376727/stopping-default-form-submit-in-bootstrap-validator-form

Comment: Well, I can see the code in my edit get initialized, but when clicking on the submit button, I get an error stating "this object or property doesn't support this method". Which, basically means, the "formValidation.min.js" file I have in my project doesn't support the "bootstrapValidator" object. I have tried several links to get the proper JS file into my project for the validation, but I get the same error each time. I just wish someone could definitively tell me where exactly I can download the validator and what folder in the zip file it would be in, because now, I'm frustrated.

Comment: Ok, you need to include the css and js (you could use CDN, check CDN section in http://bootstrapvalidator.com/download/). Also i think this example could help you: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/modal/

Comment: Patrick LC, thanks a lot for your input. I took a very close look at the example at the following url (http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/) and understood completely. However, my simple form only validates if I start typing in it; the submit button will get disabled. If I go into the form right away and click the submit button, it doesn't fire the validation. I was hoping you could take a look after I finish my EDIT and see what I'm missing. I'm so close....

Comment: Bootply with your code: http://www.bootply.com/UwA41Brl9y Maybe i don't understand well where is the issue now.

Comment: I took a look... The issue is that if you type nothing into the textarea and click the button, the validation should be fired, not allowing me to proceed. However, no validation messages comes up and the button should then also be disabled. All this should be handled by bootstrapValidator.